# Unable to run CN1 project

Tags: java, maven, codenameone

Trying to run CN1 test application configured and downloaded from the CN1 initializr https://start.codenameone.com/ for first run using the command: `./run.sh` on Ubuntu 20.04.5 I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.86:css (cn1-process-classes) on project testapi-common: An error occurred while compiling the CSS files.  Inputs: /home/mabook/Documentos/testapi/common/src/main/css/theme.css, output: /home/mabook/Documentos/testapi/common/target/classes/theme.res, merge file: /home/mabook/Documentos/testapi/common/target/css/theme.css -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.86:css (cn1-process-classes) on project testapi-common: An error occurred while compiling the CSS files.  Inputs: /home/mabook/Documentos/testapi/common/src/main/css/theme.css, output: /home/mabook/Documentos/testapi/common/target/classes/theme.res, merge file: /home/mabook/Documentos/testapi/common/target/css/theme.css
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :testapi-common
```

**There is no documentation about how to solve this...!!!**

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your CSS file. I'm assuming the specific problem is listed above this error message in the error logs. Can you include the full error log?
What's in the css file?

Comment: Also make sure you're using JDK 11 and not newer...

Comment: I have no edit the css theme file, and my java -version: openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18

Comment: Weird, is there any additional information in the build logs above this?